# ポインタについてなのですが

Tags: c++, ポインタ

ポインタについてなんですけど勉強不足で疑問が出てきました

今スマートフォンで動かせる環境がないので正しい構文かわかりませんが

```
void f(int *a) {*a=5;}

int main(){
　int x=1;
  f(&x);
  printf("%d",x);
  return 0;
}
```

この時の結果は5になるかと思います

```
void f(int &a) {a=5;}

int main(){
　int x=1;
  f(x);
  printf("%d",x);
  return 0;
}
```

ちゃんと試していなくて申し訳ないですが...

両方5になると思います
上の書き方と下の書き方の違いがわからないです
生成されるオブジェクトファイル？に違いはありますか

また、どちらの方がどのような所で優れてますか

Comment: 言語タグがありませんが、C++ですよね？

Comment: >上の書き方と下の書き方の違いがわからないです
については、多分sayuriさんの回答で十分なのでしょうが、

>生成されるオブジェクトファイル？に違いはありますか
については、両者の*.objをバイナリ比較すれば、違っていることがわかると思います。

本件においては上記質問内容がやや曖昧であることが回答の質と内容を左右するかもしれません。
「異なっている」および「同一である」ことの着目点、ないし、お気になさっている内容をより詳しく説明することによって、より詳しい回答を得られる可能性があります。

Answer (score 6):

前者はポインターですが、後者は参照； reference と呼ばれます。
ポインターの場合は`NULL`や`nullptr`を渡すことができてしまいバグの温床となり得ますが、参照の場合は構文上、`NULL`を渡し辛くなっているためポインターよりも安全性が増します。

またポインターの場合、単一の値を指すのか配列の先頭を指すのか不明確になりますが、参照の場合は明確に区別できる点も安全な記述と言えます。

```
void f(int* a);        // 単一もしくは配列の先頭を指すポインター
void f(int& a);        // 単一の参照
void f(int (&a)[10]);  // 配列の参照
```

---

ポインターはC言語・C++言語の両方に存在しますが、参照はC++言語だけでC言語には存在しません。またC言語では戻り値を省略したり後から関数を定義することができますが、C++言語では戻り値は省略できず先に宣言する必要があります。

Comment: 「戻り値を省略したり後から関数を定義することができます」 `int`が省略できたり、暗黙に関数の型を仮定することを言ってますか？ ちょっと語弊のある表現だと思います。

Comment: @BLUEPIXY さん、質問文に挙げられていたコードがそうなっていたにもかかわらず、C++にしか存在しない参照に関する質問でしたので、質問文を編集の上で言及しました。

Answer (score 3):

最終的に生成される機械語は高い強度の最適化をかけ非デバッグモードのとき、
参照とポインタで同じものになる処理系がほとんどだと思われます。
（違う機械語が生成される必然がある状況が思いつかない）
よって「動作速度面での優劣」は一切無いと考えてさしつかえありません。

「ソースコード記述面での優劣」は状況次第でしょうか。
新しいぶんだけ参照のほうが安全に使えることが多いでしょう。
昔からあるぶんだけポインタのほうが([c](/questions/tagged/c)言語ユーザには)親しまれているでしょう。
ポインタなら nullptr を渡せますが、これは欠点でもあり利点でもあります。
ポインタなら「配列の先頭」を渡して配列丸ごとを扱えますが、これも欠点でもあり利点でもあります。

[c](/questions/tagged/c) には参照はありませんのでポインタを使わざるを得ません。
[c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) に限定すればポインタの利用を廃して参照だけでソース書くことも可能です。
(ちょっと語弊があるかも・・・)
が、そもそもポインタをまったく使わないのであれば [c](/questions/tagged/c) や [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) ではなくて
もっと新しい別の言語を使うほうが圧倒的に簡単で楽できそうな気がします。